# How should I go about making a Pathfinder 3.5 Drow Sorcerer?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, character-creation, sorcerer, drow

This is probably an odd question but here goes.

I’m going to be joining a home-brew campaign for Pathfinder 3.5 which from what I’ve been told about this campaign by the DM it’s going to follow the core rules of 3.5 and from talking with the DM I told them I was interested in playing a Drow Sorcerer.

From our conversation I could tell they were hesitant but ultimately said that if I could make it work then I could do it. For playing a game like this for the first time and this character type is probably a bad choice but I like to make my life hard.

From my own reasearch I found out about Drizzt and I’m trying to avoid being that player with a Drizzt clone.

In this world the DM told me Drow haven’t been since ‘The Great War’ where the continent was broken up into separate empires (humans, elves, dwarves etc) in order to explain this character being in the Elven kingdom they being male was abandoned in one of the cave systems close to the surface and was found by an Elven wizard and grew up basically out of sight with normal elves as parents. (Thinking about having him know nothing of being a Drow and grew up with the belief it was a magical accident that disfigured him.)

The DM was going to give me ‘The Hat of Disguise’ instead of a magic weapon I believe (i’ll be talking about it with them since I’m just trying get a head start on all the stuff I need to learn and read up on.) to allow me to hide my character’s Drow characteristics.

In this setting all children of magical nature are forced to enroll in magical academies in their empire capitals so when my characters sorcerer abilities manifested and that’s as far story wise I got.

I’ve been using this [PC Drow Variant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-drow/) for racial traits and this page on [Sorcerers](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/) from the d20pfsrd site.

What would be your recommendations for what I should look into as a starting point with this character?